# oracle missing keyword when creating table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, create-table

I am trying to create a table using sql in oracle. But using this statement it gives me missing keyword error. But it runs okay in w3school sql tryit editor. can anyone please help me to understand what causing the problem in oracle??

```
create table  products (product_key number(4) not null primary key, product_name varchar(50) not null unique, price_reg double(1000,2) not null, price_spec double(1000,2) not null, sell_reg double(1000,2) not null, sell_spec double(1000,2) not null)
```

all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another good example why w3fools is not a good resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that Oracle has a Double Precision data type and a Numeric data type. You are combining the two. The "missing keyword" here is the word "precision" after double. You either want this:

```
create table  products (
product_key number(4) not null primary key, 
product_name varchar(50) not null unique, 
price_reg double precision not null, 
price_spec double precision not null, 
sell_reg double precision not null, 
sell_spec double precision not null)
```

or this:

```
create table  products (
product_key number(4) not null primary key, 
product_name varchar(50) not null unique, 
price_reg numeric(10,2) not null, 
price_spec numeric(10,2) not null, 
sell_reg numeric(10,2) not null, 
sell_spec numeric(10,2) not null)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f27/1)

Also note that 1000 is not a valid precision value for the numeric type, the max is 38 (I used 10 above).

Answer (score 2):

try not to use w3school use oracle docs
already answer given

here are some useful information

1. Singular names for tables
2. Singular names for columns
3. Schema name for tables prefix (E.g.: SchemeName.TableName)
4. Pascal casing (a.k.a. upper camel case )

`create table  Product (
product_key number(4) not null primary key, 
product_name varchar(50) not null unique, 
price_reg double precision not null, 
price_spec double precision not null, 
sell_reg double precision not null, 
sell_spec double precision not null)`